# How to see read and write calls (including hidden characters like \n) with dtrace

Tags: c, bash, macos, dtrace

I am new to dtrace, having previously had the luxury of Linux strace tracking everything I need by default.
How to get tracking read and write calls from a running C program to work on dtrace?

I've seen the answer here: [dtrace: doesn't catch any write sys call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051417/dtrace-doesnt-catch-any-write-sys-call) ,however it doesn't help me fully.

I've added a printf statement from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5488/gcgkk.html, 
with the current code:`sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::read:entry, syscall::write:entry/pid==10325/{printf("%s",copyinstr(arg1)); }'`, where pid is the process I want to track.

However, this prints it out as a string, as opposed to in byte form. Is there a way to view the entire contents, including hidden characters like \r and \n?
This is the way it is done in strace.

Additionally, write:entry seems to cut off output after roughly 150-200 characters, is there a way to disable or increase that limit?

Comment: You can use `%S` (capital S) and it should print out all non-printable characters such as `\r` or `\n` as escape sequences.  It will still stop on the first zero `char` value, though.

Comment: Thank you, that should be good enough for most basic tracking needs. 

write:entry also seems to cut off after printing roughly 200-300 characters for some reason.

Comment: @AndrewHenle want to post that as an answer?